# adding UICollectionViewCell with dynamically changed cell width makes minimumInteritemSpacing no effect?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

In the demo project I can  press "add a new tag"button to add a UICollectionViewCell whoes label contains my newly input text.

This is the target effect:

[image: target effect]

This is current situation:
[image: wrong effect]

In the current state, i reconfigure cell UI in cellForItemAtIndexPath function and resize cell size in sizeForItemAtIndexPath function.   But these operations seem cause the minimumInteritemSpacing not work. I use the UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, and overwrite method -

`-(NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>  
@interface CustomViewFlowLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout

@property(nonatomic) CGFloat maximumLineSpacing;

@end

@implementation CustomlViewFlowLayout

- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSArray *answer = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];
    for(int i = 1; i < answer.count; ++i) {
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *currentLayoutAttributes = answer[i];
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *prevLayoutAttributes = answer[i - 1];

        NSInteger maximumSpacing = self.maximumLineSpacing;
        NSInteger origin = CGRectGetMaxX(prevLayoutAttributes.frame);

        if(origin + maximumSpacing + currentLayoutAttributes.frame.size.width < self.collectionViewContentSize.width) {
            CGRect frame = currentLayoutAttributes.frame;
            frame.origin.x = origin + maximumSpacing;
            currentLayoutAttributes.frame = frame;
        }
        if (currentLayoutAttributes.frame.origin.y != prevLayoutAttributes.frame.origin.y) {
            CGRect frame = currentLayoutAttributes.frame;
            frame.origin.x = 0;
            currentLayoutAttributes.frame = frame;
        }
    }
    return answer;
}

@end
```

the property `maximumLineSpacing` used to set the max line space